# AWS S3 ultra slow speed

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using S3 as an image repository, the image are already there and I just download them: https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/my-image.jpg.

The problem is I'm having **extremely** slow speed, I'm talking about **1.2 minutes** to download a **600 KB image**, what is this, 1992??

- Tested directly on *Google Chrome*, using the *Network* tool in *Developer Console*

Tested on

I'm located in **Central America** or **Latin America** (whatever you call it), and I have tried buckets from **Brazil** and **EU West** (which are the nearest geographically), being the fastest **EU West**.

We are currently using *Free Tier* as we are testing how confortable we are with this IaaS service, but they didn't mention anything about slow speed on free tier, so I don't think this is the reason?

Any ideas are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: there's definitely no "slow speed when free". Have you tried US-West-2 and US-East-1? Peering in central america can be weird.

Comment: how did you resolve this eventually?

Answer (score 1):

It could be your own local connection that is the problem, but none-the-less, if you want to host your images in s3, consider using amazon's cloudfront as a CDN in front of it - that will push the images to caches geographically closer to you and should improve performance.

http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

Very easy to setup and try to see if it makes a difference,